# I keep getting the same indentation error after re-arranging code multiple times

Tags: python, python-3.x, indentation

Need help with a project at school where i am getting an indentation error on the following lines of code:

```
                     #First question
while numberofquestions <10:
    operations = ['x', '-', '+']
    operation = random.choice(operations)
    number1 = random.randrange(0,10)
    number2 = random.randrange(0,10)
    if operation == '+':
        answer = number1 + number2
    elif operation == '-':
        answer = number1 - number2
    elif operation == 'x':
        answer = number1 * number2
    while True:
        try:
                user_answer = input("What is " + str(number1) + " " + operation + " " + str(number2) + "?")
                user_answer = float(user_answer)
        except ValueError:
                print("Sorry that was an incorrect input, please try again.")
            else:
                break
    if user_answer == answer:
        print("Well Done! You got it correct!")
        score = score+1
    else:
        print("Sorry you got that wrong")
    print ("***********-*-*-*-Your score so far is-*-*-*-*********** ")
    print (score)
    numberofquestions = numberofquestions+1
print ("Well done, you have completed your test! Your final score was...")
print (score)
```

The individual error itself is in the line:

```
while True:
        try:
```

And the error I get is "unindent does not match any outer indentation level"

Here is a link containing my whole code incase it helps: http://paste.ubuntu.com/17167322/

Comment: The block starts in `while True:` but the error is on the `else` line which is visibly badly aligned here and on pastbin too. But my IDLE directly showed me the offending line...

Answer (score 2):

These lines:

```
while True:
        try:
                user_answer = input("What is " + str(number1) + " " + operation + " " + str(number2) + "?")
                user_answer = float(user_answer)
        except ValueError:
                print("Sorry that was an incorrect input, please try again.")
            else:
                break
```

Have wrong indentation.

The two `user_answer` lines have one extra indention, and the `else` block has no matching `if` or `try/except` block.

Answer (score 2):

**Always set editor to CONVERT TAB TO WHITESPACE**.

Never ever save tab as indentation, most parser that deal with indentation don't know how to handle mix of tab and spaces. This is the most common problem for all new developer that deal with indentation syntax  (python , yaml, etc)

I spot the issue ASAP by copy your code to Notepad++, turn on "show all character".  From line 67 to 74, you use space as indentation, while the rest you are using TAB.  Depends on editor, some call the function as "Replace Tab by space", "Save tab as space" ,"translate tabs to spaces"

```
    while True:
    try:
            ....
    except ValueError:
            print("Sorry that was an incorrect input, please try again.")
    ###### Here is indentation error culprit, mostly due to tab/space mix.
        else:
            break
```